# How many lines can be created using the 6 vertices from a rectangular prism and 2 other points?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I got this prism

[image]

> How many lines can be formed by the vertices of the prism and the
> points I and J?

I did:

- Combinations between the vertices = $^8C_2 = 28$
- Combinations of 1 vertex and either I or J = $^8C_1 \cdot ^2C_1 = 16$
- Combinations between I and J = $1$
- Total = $28 + 16 + 1 = 45$

But my book says the solution is 41. What did I do wrong?

$$\\$$

I admit the problem isn't very clear. I am not sure if what is wanted is only the combinations between one vertex and either I or J or the combinations between all of them. I copied the problem as it is.

Answer (score 2):

You double-counted a few lines. For instance, the line between C and J was already created by C and F, etc.

Comment: Ah, so to do this right I have to subtract all cases in which that happens, which are (C,J) , (C,I) , (D,I) and (F,J), so $45-4 = 41$. Thanks